# excel vlookup in tables - search for row and report value in column using column name

Tags: excel

I have a database table that is structured like this

```
SAP Number, FOW, WD, DG
```

In a different sheet I am using data from this list
It looks like this

```
SAP Number, WD, DG, ....
```

The SAP Number is given, WD and DG are searched using VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Objektive!$B:$M,10,FALSE)
```

This however is difficult to read and could be solved much easier.
I know that the search value is in $A2, and I know that the value is in a tabular named "WD". 
Is it possible within Excel to search for the Row similar ot VLOOKUP, but use the column using the column name as `[@[WD]]`

Here some peudo-code

```
=VLOOKUPTABLE($A2,Data[@[WD]],FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data table starts from the first column, you can use the COLUMN function to determine the index of the column you want to return data from in the table using the name of that column.

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Data,COLUMN(Data[WD]),FALSE)
```

Alternatively you can use Index/Match to directly reference the columns you want to match and return data from.

```
=INDEX(Data[WD], MATCH($A2, Data[SAP Number], 0))
```

Comment: The first gives me `#NV`back, whereas the second works. Code used is 
`=SVERWEIS($A2;Data;SPALTE(Data[Short Name]);FALSCH)`
`=INDEX(Data[Short Name]; VERGLEICH($A3; Data[SAP Nummer]; 0))`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table from the Excel (select any of the cells and press Ctrl + T) you gain access to named references which you can use in Excel formulas. Just make sure your data contains headers.

Comment: My data contains headers, but I do not see how your answer resolves my problem. Maybe you can post some code to show what you mean.

Comment: Don't have Excel here, but if you turn your data into a table via `Ctrl + T` or `Insert > Table` you can use the column names (that's why you need headers) to access certain data. Maybe this link will help: https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/excel-named-ranges-with-vlookup-formula-excel/